# Kentico. Send email to a specific address in a form table.

Tags: email, kentico

So I have a form that captures or saves an email address.  I need to send an email to that email address.  I realize there is the standard email notification field in Kentico forms.  However that is for the 'one' email you would put in that will send the results to.  I need to send an email to a stored email, or one that was added via form submission to a form table.  Any way to do this or massage the email notification option under forms?  Thanks!!

Comment: Figured out a way or actually an option on the Forms menu I was not initially aware of; "Autoresponder."  Autoresponder will send an email to the last submission made to the form.  Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AUtoresponder like you mentioned or you can use the Email Notification, and for the email address just use a macro to pull from the form   `{%Emailinput%}`  with EmailInput being the field code name.